# How to update google-services.json file in Android studio?

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I am using Firebase in an android project. I want to change to a new Firebase project. How can I update my google-services.json File in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Download the new google-services.json from Firebase Console and put it **at the root of the Android Studio app module**

[image]